# Can you solve the following algebraic equation for one variable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Could anyone help me solve the following equation for $F$:

$$P=\left|\sqrt{F^2+G^2+2FG\cos(2a)}\right|$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In the future, to get responses that suit your needs, please include **in the body of the question** your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You should have
$$F_1= \frac{-2 G \cos[2 a] - \sqrt 2 \sqrt{G^2 + 2 P^2 + G^2 \cos[4 a]}}{2},$$
and
$$F_2= \frac{-2 G \cos[2 a] + \sqrt 2 \sqrt{G^2 + 2 P^2 + G^2 \cos[4 a]}}{2},$$
because your equations can be manipulated as a simple quadratic  one.

Answer (score 1):

Squaring both sides,
$$
P^2 = F^2 + G^2 +2FG\cos{2a} \implies F^2 + (2G\cos{2a})F+G^2-P^2=0
$$

This is a quadratic in $F$.

Solving, you get,
$$
F = -G\cos{2a} \pm \sqrt{P^2-(G\sin{2a})^2} 
$$